# How complexity of BigInteger consecutive methods are calculated?

Tags: complexity-theory, biginteger

Assume that the methods of BigInteger are called as below:

res = res.multiply(b).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).mod(n);

Here, how do we calculate time complexity of this statement?

Do we think them as nested? If so, we will multiply complexities of multiply, subtract and mod methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them creates a loop, therefore there is no reason to consider them as nested. They simply follow each other. Their complexity is not multiplied, only added.